# C#, Datagrid, Search part of a string

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, filter

According to my code below, I can filter datagridview when I start to enter the text in tbxSearch text box.

But it only works if i type the text in order.

Example: If I Started to type "D001-A" it is started to filtering the text starting from "D001-A".

If I enter "001-A" it is not filtering as the text is in middle of the string.
Any advise please.

```
 private void tbxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                (dgvTracking.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("DocumentNo LIKE '{0}%'", tbxSearch.Text);                

}
```

Comment: `string.Format("DocumentNo LIKE '%{0}%'", tbxSearch.Text);`

Comment: "DocumentNo LIKE '%{0}%'"

Comment: That's not enough if the tbxSearch text contains a single quote. You need also a Replace to duplicate the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `string.Format("DocumentNo LIKE '{0}%'", tbxSearch.Text);` to `string.Format("DocumentNo LIKE '%{0}%'", tbxSearch.Text);`

In your example it searching strings only starting with your parameter ('string%'), you need to add `%` from the begging, which will mean, that it will match result, if string will found in any place.

Comment: it's working. Appreciate your time SeM - ՍեՄ, i3lai3la adn Steve